# Descending Sorting of an ArrayList of Object

Tags: sorting, arraylist, hashmap, descendant

I need to sort this ArrayObject :

```
public ArrayList<WPPost> posts;
```

on descending :

```
posts.get(i).getRating()
```

I have tried with HashMaps, LinkedHashMaps, I haven't found anything. What's the best solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that one of the best solutions is the use of Collections.sort

```
    Collections.sort(posts, new Comparator<WPPost>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(WPPost o1, WPPost o2) {
            return o2.getRating() - o1.getRating();
        }
    });
```

In some implemetations Collectios sort use **merge sort** algorithm, that will give you a O(log n) complexity.